# how to calculate distance between 2 red pixel

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a video file with 2 dot laser and I want to calculate the distance in pixels between them, I tried this code with OpenCV, but it is not working  :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAgbc.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\Test\VID_20200609_195155.mp4')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
old = 0

while (1):

    # Take each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([0, 0, 255])
    upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    # cv2.imshow('Track Laser', frame)
    moments = cv2.moments(hsv[:, :, 2])


    output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, 8, cv2.CV_32S)


    print (output[3])
    print ("----**----")
    if moments["m00"] > 0:
        x = (moments['m10']/ moments['m00'])
        y = (moments['m01']/ moments['m00'])
        #print(moments['m00'],moments['m01'],moments['m10'])
        #print(x, y)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break




cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this code `output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, 8, cv2.CV_32S)` give me the centroid of points , but how to geat each point(laser dot) separately ? if I get the centroid I can measure the distance between these points

Comment: first you have to find positions `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` and later use Pythagorean formula - `a**2 + b**2 = c**2` which means `(x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 = distance**2`

Comment: @RolandDeschain  I edited the code, the problem now with the centroid, can you take a look

Comment: @furas , the problem ow how to get the centroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your other way to do that in Python/OpenCV using connectedComponentsWithStats.

- Read the input
- Set min and max red colors
- Use cv2.inRange() to threshold on the color range
- Apply morphology open and close to clean up small spots and holes
- Process with connectedComponentsWithStats to get the labels and centroids
- Extract all the areas corresponding to the labels and centroids
- For all labels, test if the area is smaller than some estimate of the background, as we want to exclude that centroid. Draw the label as a filled yellow region on a copy of the input. Extract the centroids of small regions and store in pts array. Draw the centroids as small green squares on the copy of the input.
- For all saved points, compute the distance between successive ones.
- Save the output

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read image
frame = cv2.imread('red_spots.jpg')
hh, ww = frame.shape[:2]

# convert to hsv   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold image
lower_red = np.array([0, 0, 225])
upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# apply close and open morphology to smooth
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# do connected components processing
nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(morph, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_16U)

# get all areas from stats[label_start_id:label_stop_id, area_flag] 
areas = stats[0:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]

# draw labels and get centroids and draw centroids
result = frame.copy()
pts = []
for i in range(0, nlabels):
    if areas[i] <= ww*hh/5 :
        # labels start at 1 not 0
        result[labels == i+1] = (0,255,255)
        pt = centroids[i]
        pts.append(pt)
        cx = pt[0]
        cy = pt[1]
        x = int(round(cx))
        y = int(round(cy))
        # draw small square at centroids
        result[y-2:y+3,x-2:x+3] = (0,255,0)
        print('centroid =',cx,",",cy)

number = len(pts)   
for i in range(number-1):
    pt1 = pts[i]
    x1 = pt1[0]
    y1 = pt1[1]
    pt2 = pts[i+1]
    x2 = pt2[0]
    y2 = pt2[1]
    dist = math.sqrt( (x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 )
    print('distance =', dist)
    print('')

#save images
cv2.imwrite('red_spots_thresh2.jpg',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('red_spots_morph2.jpg',morph)
cv2.imwrite('red_spots_centroids2.jpg',result)

# show images
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Result image with colored region labels and centroids:

[image]

Centroids and Distances:

```
centroid = 1006.7307283673711 , 433.70499350726004
centroid = 1036.418693371483 , 750.4024797329519
distance = 318.08595229553544
```

Answer (score 1):

Distance is the square root of the sum of the squares of the x difference and the y difference. So

```
import math

dist = math.sqrt( (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 )
```

for points x1,y1 and x2,y2

Comment: I edited my code, the problem now with centroid, can you take a look

Comment: You do not need to compute moments and the centroid. The centroid is returned from connectedComponentsWithStats. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f. If you really want to compute moments, then compute them from contours. So you need to findContours on your thresholded image and then compute moments as follows: `  M = cv2.moments(cntr)
  cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
  cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])   
`

Comment: but I have two-point, this centroid returned from connectedComponentsWithStats , for the first point or for the second point?

Comment: connectedComponentsWithStats should give you a list of x,y centroids for each region in the thresholded image. If you have 2 regions, then you should get 2 sets of x,y values plus one for the background to make 3. Each is associated with a label. See the documentation I listed earlier. `centroid output for each label, including the background label. Centroids are accessed via centroids(label, 0) for x and centroids(label, 1) for y. The data type CV_64F.`

Comment: If you post a link to your image, I will try to create a script for you.

Comment: I do not see any link to your input image! Just one example frame will do. Once I show you that, then you can modify it for looping over all your frames.

Comment: I post link for image , check it

Comment: You can use the function cv2.magnitude() to calculate the Euclidean distance.

Comment: True. I had not thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. The function cv2.InRange() to find two red dots.
2. The function cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats() to find the centroids of these red points.
3. Calculate the Euclidean distance between centroids.

Also, you can select points by brightness only, without even using their color.

```
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('HAgbc.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.normalize(gray, gray,  0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
points=cv2.threshold(gray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )[1]
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(points, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
centroids = output[3]
x,y=(centroids[1]-centroids[2])
dist=cv2.magnitude(x, y)[0]
print('distance is: ', *dist)
```

Or this code (find two brightness maximum):

```
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('HAgbc.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
pos1=cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)[3]
cv2.circle(gray, pos1, 30, 0, -1) # masking first spot
pos2=cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)[3]
x=pos1[0]-pos2[0]
y=pos1[1]-pos2[1]
dist=cv2.magnitude(x, y)[0]
print('distance is: ', *dist)
```

Comment: how to use cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()

Comment: i get the centroid by using this code output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, 8, cv2.CV_32S)     print (output[3]) but but how to geat each point(laser dot) separately to measure distance ?

Comment: See the answer to @fmw42, everything is explained in detail to him.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do your processing in Python/OpenCV using contours.

- Read the input
- Set min and max red colors
- Use cv2.inRange() to threshold on the color range
- Apply morphology open and close to clean up small spots and holes
- Find contours
- For each contour, draw the contour, use moments to compute the centroid, save the centroids in a list and draw a small square at the centroid location
- For each successive pair of centroid points, compute the distance between them in pixels
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read image
frame = cv2.imread('red_spots.jpg')

# convert to hsv   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold image
lower_red = np.array([0, 0, 225])
upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# apply close and open morphology to smooth
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# draw contours and get centroids
spots = frame.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
pts = []
count = 0
for c in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(spots, [c], -1, (0,255,0), 2)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = M["m10"] / M["m00"]
    cy = M["m01"] / M["m00"]
    pt = (cx,cy)
    pts.append(pt)
    x = round(cx)
    y = round(cy)
    # draw small square at centroids
    spots[y-2:y+3,x-2:x+3] = (255,0,0)
    print('centroid =',cx,",",cy)
    count = count + 1

for i in range(count-1):
    pt1 = pts[i]
    x1 = pt1[0]
    y1 = pt1[1]
    pt2 = pts[i+1]
    x2 = pt2[0]
    y2 = pt2[1]
    dist = math.sqrt( (x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 )
    print('distance =', dist)
    print('')

#save images
cv2.imwrite('red_spots_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('red_spots_morph.png',morph)
cv2.imwrite('red_spots_centroids.png',spots)

# show images
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("spots", spots)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Contours and centroids image:

[image]

Centroids and Distances:

```
centroid = 1036.4038142620232 , 750.3941127694858
centroid = 1006.6605586230609 , 433.9662237323787
distance = 317.8227024875417
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thank you very much you save my life